# Stored Number with dot but display with comma in frontend

Tags: c#, .net, globalization

The data type in database is "decimal", the value is normally like 2.6, 3.8 etc

But when I render it on the front side, it become 2,6
I wondering why it happens and how to handle it correctly.

I try to adjust .Net Globalization Culture in IIS become EN, then display as I want.
Not the setting is Invariant Language. 
I had print out culture info by C#, it shows GB

How can I handling it as all display number with dot

Comment: Frontend? WPF, winforms, anything else?

Comment: The storage format in the database is irrelevant, what's the type within C# /.NET? `decimal`/`float`/`double`, etc...

Comment: @MightyBadaboom Frontend use jQuery to render, I found out when the data at frontend is already with comma, I guess I should to change backend, the backend write by .Net C#

Comment: @JNYRanger - the C#/.NET type is also irrelevant...

Comment: @JNYRanger in C# I use decimal column in Object to receive it

Comment: So your FrontEnd is on another PC... Somewhere along a long line of steps the value is converted to a string. Usually we do that as late as possible, and with the User's culture. You first have to find out where it is converted exactly... Is there a comma in the JSon?

Comment: @HenkHolterman when I use VS debug mode, it display dot, but when I use local IIS to run it shows Comma, my laptop is bought in Germany and its original a German Windows, is it possible to change culture info each time the website load? like a session for whole website

Comment: @HenkHolterman touche, i was thinking along the lines of the `ToString()` formatting methods, but this is a globalization issue

Comment: @Kun-yaoWang - what you see in the debugger is yet another setting... But do pay attention to whether it's a `string` or a `decimal` you're looking at.

Comment: And how to manage on your website depends on your website... It probably isn't a C#/.NET question at all. Maybe a little bit MVC.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I united whole process is decimal, database, object, it seems render different depend on Culture info, i write a function and put at begin of each time when search clicked, even thought it looks working, but i think that is not the best way

Comment: @HenkHolterman
public void setGlob()
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        }